# What happened to geometry simulation nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

[Simulation nodes](https://code.blender.org/2022/11/geometry-nodes-workshop-2022/#simulation-nodes) were one of the [experimental branches](https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/geometry-nodes-simulation/) for 3.5. Now the branch is archived, and the simulation nodes are missing from the 3.5 beta version. They are also missing from 3.6 alpha release notes.

Is the simulation nodes branch abandoned or will it be merged at some (which) future release?

Comment: I don’t feel like this is the right place to ask this question, but at the same time, I feel it is a good one, and I don’t know where you would ask it.

Comment: This may be a good question, but strictly speaking it does not refer to "using Blender" as defined in the rules of this Q&A platform, since *Simulation Nodes* are simply not part of Blender (yet). You might find more information about this in the [developer forum](https://devtalk.blender.org/).

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software.

Comment: i am still searhing for answer..let me know if someone got idea, thanks in advance

Comment: The work is tracked via [this ticket](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/104924).